# Deleting the pixels from BufferedImage

Tags: java, image, server, stream, byte

So, I'm trying to establish a live stream of the webcam through the server. After much research, I tried to only send the difference in the frames.

Here is my code:

```
for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {                    
        if (image.getRGB(x, y) == previousImage.getRGB(x, y) {
            image.setRGB(x, y, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

However, this actually leads in an increase in bytes! Is it possible to 'delete' pixels? To have less bytes overall, yet still not be a corrupted jpeg?

Also, are there any alternatives to what I'm doing?

Your help is greatly appreciated! Thank you! :)

Comment: Well, you're not actually "deleting" anything there, you're just changing its color; and if the surrounding pixels aren't black, then you're just increasing the higher-frequency components needed to encode the image, which is why the byte size increases. If you want to send video efficiently, use a codec which has been designed specifically for this purpose.

Comment: @AndyTurner yes, I did realize my mistake after I implemented it this way. However, isn't there really a way to 'delete' them?

Comment: Deleting them would change the size of the image, how would you know which pixel in the new image matched which pixel in the original? If, you're going to generate a delta, you also need to know the x/y position of the pixel that's changed